# Google Apps Script doesn't find file

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I just want to check, if a file already exists on my Google Drive:

```
var Filename = 'xyz';
var Files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(Filename);
if (Files.hasNext()) { ... }
```

This did work very good for some month. But suddenly it stopped working a few weeks ago. Now the result of hasNext() is always false - although the filename definitely does exist.

Did anything change at Google Apps Script? Is anything wrong with my code? Can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found how to retrieve files with filename included umlauts. Please confirm this. `title contains` was required as a query. It was not `title=`. Please confirm the following script for your script.

#### Script :

```
var name = "Übergabe News";
var Files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "' + name + '" and trashed=false');
if (Files.hasNext()) { ... }
```

Also you can use this for "20170817 Nachrichten-Übergabe" in your comments. I'm sorry for being late solution.

Comment: Oh. You are right. But it was just wrong in the question above. In the original code, I have used the string variable. But it doesn't work for a few weeks now. I don't understand why. Because it did work before and I didn't change anything in the script.

Comment: @wepli23 For example, in order to confirm whether ``getFilesByName()`` can be used, how about the creation of new file (Spreadsheet as a sample) with the name of ``xyz`` and run an added script in my answer? If there are some files with ``xyz``, you can see the log.

Comment: I have tried different things now. As a fact, DriveApp.getFilesByName(Filename) simply doesn't find some files, it did definitely find before. There all are in a specific folder. But DriveApp searches everywhere, right?

Comment: @wepli23 As a next confirmation, can you try to create new project and run this script? Because I thought that the existing project body may have some errors.

Comment: Thank you. I also tried a new project, but it doesn't work too. I just don't get it... For example: In my Google Drive are the Files "Übergabe News" and "20170817 Nachrichten-Übersicht" side by side. They both have completely the same shares. `getFilesByName()` does find "Übergabe News" but not "20170817 Nachrichten-Übergabe"... Why?

Comment: @wepli23 In my experience, the filename with umlauts cannot be searched using ``getFilesByName()``. Had you ever tried to search the filename without umlauts using ``getFilesByName()``? I couldn't notice about your filename. I'm sorry.

Comment: You are right. Thank you! If I rename the file to "20170817 Nachrichten-Uebergabe" `getFilesByName()` does find it. Very good! But why did this work for many month before? And why does it find "Übergabe News" which has the same umlaut? Strange...

Comment: @wepli23 There are various modifications by recent updates of Google. This may be one of them. But I think that the special characters except for the alphabetical characters are also used for filename by a lot of people. So I want to expect that this current situation is modified in the future. And I'm sorry for taking your time. I hope that this may be a solution for your current situation.

Comment: @wepli23 Finally, I could find how to retrieve files with filename included special characters. I updated my answer. Please confirm it.